# System.EnterpriseServices Error when trying to connect Excel or PowerBI to a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel

I just setup a new SQL server and am trying to connect Excel and PowerBI to it. I'm getting an error that says the following:

**Unable to connect
Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)'"**

In researching this error, the following steps were suggested.

- 1: Run Excel or PowerBI as Admin
- 2: Reinstall .NetFramework
- 3: Modify PBIX file (specific to PowerBI)
- 4: Connect via SQL Authentication instead of Windows Authentication

None of these solutions worked.

I am able to connect to the SQL server with SSMS and Azure Data Studio with both Windows and SQL authentication on the client computer (as well as on the server itself), but when I try to connect via Excel or PowerBI I get the above error.

I tried on a freshly imaged computer and get the same error.

Please help!! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I also successfully connect via sqlcmd and Powershell. It's only Excel and PowerBI I get this error.

Comment: I've made some progress on this error. I have identified the GPO that is causing this error. It's Policies -> Windows Settings -> Restricted Groups. Doesn't make sense, but when Restricted Groups is defined, Excel and PowerBI get a connection error when trying to connect to a SQL server.

Comment: Upon further testing,.. anytime local Administrators/builtin group has any definition in Group Policy from the Domain, Excel and PowerBI connection to SQL server doesn't work. Anyone know why this would be so?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Ended up adding a User DSN that connects to the SQL Server database and then connecting to the database via ODBC rather than connecting by the obvious choice "From a SQL Server Database".   Always love dealing with Microsoft oddities.

Comment: That is a work-around, not a solution and bypasses the problem which is a corrupt or missing DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Power BI Desktop, connecting to SQL Server.  The answer [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-System-EnterpriseServices/m-p/3669051#M1198833) worked for me, which was to delete all my existing credentials to the SQL Server.

1. In the File menu, click on Options and Settings
2. Click on Data Source Settings
3. Filter the list to show all connections for the target server
4. Delete each one
5. Restart Power BI Desktop (not sure if this is needed or not)